# Quiting the page before a form submission

Tags: asp.net, javascript

In my application I am showing the warning message when the user want to leave the page before submitting the form. I am using  window.onbeforeunload() in the script. My application has a Master page.

I have four different views for a single form. I am inserting record in first view itself.
When user quits the page I want to make some DB change(deletion of record). That's why I want to call a server side function from the script.

How to do it  ? Can anybody suggest something ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using [jQuery + ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) in your onbeforeunload handler.

Answer (score 0):

The URL that the JavaScript calls should be a form with an onLoad method that does wha tyou need.